# paypal rest api fro future payments

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to implement future payments using nodejs. 
I am using following code to get users consent for future payments.

```
'use strict';
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
const openIdConnect = paypal.openIdConnect;

// OpenID configuration
paypal.configure({
   'mode': 'sandbox',
   'openid_client_id': 'XXXX',
   'openid_client_secret': 'XXXX',
   'openid_redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/callback'
});

// Authorize url
const url = openIdConnect.authorizeUrl({'scope':  'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/futurepayments'});

app.get('/paypal', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(url);
})

app.get('/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('response:'+ JSON.stringify(req.query.code));
})
```

So from above code I was able to get Authorization code. But now how can I use that code to get refresh token and access token? 
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After trying couple of things, I used

```
 openIdConnect.tokeninfo.create("auth code", callback)
```

which gave me refresh token and access token.

Thanks